# how to convert list of model objects to list of object arrays java

Tags: java

How to convert a list of model  objects to list of object arrays java

Like example `List<Model> newlist = new ArrayList<Model>();` This is my which I want to convert into List

How will I do it?

Comment: Your `ArrayList` is already a `List` if that's what you're asking

Comment: Hm, t's more: transform a `List<M>` to `List<Object[]>`. If you add the relevant code for M and the way you want to transform it, one could proceed from there. Otherwise its just guess-work. One transformation would be: throw away M entirely, create an empty Object[]. Probably not, what you want.

Comment: I want convert List<Model> list to List<Object[]> list   means i have list List<Model> mylist=new Arraylist<Model>(); This i want convert into List<Object[]>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, let's stick to the requirements. Seems to make not much sense, but there it is:

```
List<Object[]> transformed = list.stream().map(i -> new Object[]{i}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And a java 5 version with 2 possible varieties of creating Object[] from an objcect.

```
 class C {
    public final Long id;
    public final String value;

    C(Long id, String value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }
}


public void objectify() {
    List<C> items = Arrays.asList(new C(0L, "a"), new C(1L, "b"));
    List<Object[]> coarse = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Object[]> detailed = new ArrayList<>();
    for (C c: items)
    {
        coarse.add(new Object[]{c});
        detailed.add(new Object[]{c.id, c.value});
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please help me for this code to use in java 7 or 6? because i m using java 6

Comment: i am facing another when i m storing  for (C c: items)
    {
        coarse.add(new Object[]{c});
        detailed.add(new Object[]{c.id, c.value});
    }   it is storing only last element repeatedly

Comment: I think, you will face all kind of issues with the approach taken, and nobody even can comment on it without knowledge of the code.

Answer (score 0):

To convert array to list you can use

```
List<Object> list = Arrays.asList(ObjectOne, ObjectTwo)
```

or to convert list to array

```
Object[] array = list.toArray();
```

Comment: I want convert List<Model> list to List<Object[]> list

Comment: I want convert List<Model> list to List<Object[]> list means i have list List<Model> mylist=new Arraylist<Model>(); This i want convert into List<Object[]>